# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting: Highlight cell that contains text found in list (dynamic list)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, contains

I'm looking for help in finding the proper conditional formatting formula to highlight the cell if it contains a word found in a list I've made in another column. I'd like this list to be dynamic where I will add in more words in the future.

Example:

**Column A (conditional formatting to apply)**------------**Column B (dynamic list)**

2015 AUDI Q7 (*highlight)------------------------------------------------Transit

2021 HYUNDAI ELANTRA ---------------------------------------Rogue

2019 FORD ESCAPE -------------------------------------------Q7

2019 FORD TRANSIT VAN (*highlight) -------------------------------------etc, etc

2014 CADILLAC ESCALADE

2018 CHRYSLER PACIFICA

2019 NISSAN ROGUE SPORT (*highlight)

2018 JEEP GRAND CHEROKEE

---

So within Column A, I'd like for '2015 Audi Q7', '2019 Ford Transit Van', and '2019 Nissan Rogue Sport' to be highlighted because they contain a word found in the Column B list. And if I were to add to the list in the future, it should automatically highlight the cell in Column A if applicable (i.e. if I were to add 'Escalade' to the list, then '2014 Cadillac Escalade' in Column A would be highlighted).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=regexmatch(lower($A1),lower(textjoin("|",1,$B:$B)))
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks!  Would this also work if the list is on another tab (based on your image, if Column A is in tab 1 and Column B is in tab 2)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so. It doesn't seem to work on my sample sheet.

Comment: Yes, i think you're right. I tried to add 'sheet2!' in front of the $B:$B range, but didn't seem to work. However, when doing this directly in the sheet itself (not using the conditional format formula) it seemed to work.  =regexmatch(lower($A1),lower(textjoin("|",1,Sheet2!$B:$B))) .. oh well!  But I appreciate all the help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer for when the list is in another sheet.
You could make use of `INDIRECT` function. (assume the list is in B column)

```
=REGEXMATCH(LOWER($A1), LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT("Sheet2!$B:$B"))))
```

This will work inside Conditional Formating.